# how to set a notification even if app is not running or closed

Tags: android, sqlite, notifications

how to set a notification even if the app is not running or closed. I am writing a code in which I am checking for the new data updated in RESTful web services. and if new data is updated it will notify the app user that there is the new item. just like a mail arrived and the user gets notified. I am new to this please suggest.

Comment: can I declare the service anywhere in the project to get notify ..

Comment: thanks now i understand

Comment: You are welcome! Please upvote if it helped you!

Comment: answer first comments cannot be upvoted

Comment: Updated the answer! Happy coding

Comment: you please upvote my question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use services for background checking and use notification in services so that notification fire even app is closed.

This may help:

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/04/start-service-to-send-notification.html

You can create a service class in your package and remember to add it in your manifest. Start the service when your main activity starts or use broadcast reciever and start activity inside broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 0):

@HITESH  try this
Main.java

```
public class BroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                Intent.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

Android Manifest file

```
<receiver
    android:name=".BroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name=".Intent" />
```